# Why my condicional is failling with selectizeInput()?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create two `selectizeInput()`, but one depends on another.

I mean, I have State and Region. If I have selected a especific State, I want to show only his Region in another `selectizeInput()` and vice-versa.

My UI:

```
selectizeInput("sta", "State:", 
               c("Todos", str_sort(unique(as.character(Coop_ativas$state)))),
               selected = "Todos", options = list(placeholder = 'Todos')), 

selectizeInput("regi", "region:",c("Todas", ( 
    if (Coop_ativas$region[Coop_ativas$state %in% as.character(input$sta)]) 
        str_sort(unique(as.character(Coop_ativas$region[Coop_ativas$uf %in% 
                                     as.character(input$sta)])))
    else 
        str_sort(unique(as.character(Coop_ativas$regiao))))), selected = "Todas",options = list(placeholder = 'Todas')),
```

But I have the error `Error in Coop_ativas$uf %in% as.character(input$est) :  object 'input' not found`

Can I do it without filter my db in Server?

Comment: `input` is available in the server function only. Such dependencies must be handled there.

Comment: When I'm developing a shiny app and want a quick test without starting up a shiny server (even with `runApp`), I often create a named list `input <- list(sta = "...")`, where I'm testing for specific selections that a user may make. It's a hack and should be deleted promptly (so that you don't inadvertently "poison" further shiny testing), but allows you to quickly check some things on the console.

Comment: You could do like this in a `flexdashboard`, but in a shiny app you need to use `updateSelectizeInput()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the selectizeInput from the server.
Use this in your UI (or the other choice from your condition, as you prefer).

```
selectizeInput("regi", "region:",
               choices = c("Todas"),
               selected = "Todas",options = list(placeholder = 'Todas'))
```

and then put this in your server

```
observe({
req(input$sta)
  if (Coop_ativas$region[Coop_ativas$state %in% as.character(input$sta)]) {
    choice = c("Todas", str_sort(unique(as.character(Coop_ativas$region[Coop_ativas$uf %in% as.character(input$sta)]))))
  } 
  else {
    choice = c("Todas", str_sort(unique(as.character(Coop_ativas$regiao)))))
  }
  
  updateSelectizeInput(session, "regi", choices = choice)
  
})
```

and finally make sure your server function is defined as `server <- function(input, output, session){}` rather than `server <- function(input, output){}`